# jQuery is not working in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm new to jQuery.. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.. In that I tried basic jQuery function.. But its not working.. My script coding is:

---

```
<title>
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
    });
    });
</script>
```

And my asp coding is:

---

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

---

Can anyone tell my why its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your first block of code as below:

```
<title>My Test Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"        type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
      $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
      });
    });
</script>
```

it will work.

Comment: I tried.. But still alert message is not displaying..
I removed 1st three includes and using just last one alone..

Comment: I didn't saw your including line end.. Now I changed it to </script> and its working now.. Thank a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You are including jquery multiple times on the page - both minified and regular versions.

Reduce it to just one.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one jquery js file.

remove this jquery file

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

and use only

```
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
```

this will work.

and use button like this if you are just performing jquery operation

```
<input type="button" ID="Button1" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use script tag autoclose!
2. Ad only one jquery reference.
3. Make sure that your button ID in resulting html doesn't changed?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the control from server side(asp controls).Use `ClientID` to get that control

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried.. But still alert message is not displaying..
I removed 1st three includes and using just last one alone..

Answer (score 0):

You can try after removing first three libraries:

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

and plz don't try doing inline closing of script:

```
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```